# How can i build cordova project for 64bit Android?

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, build, 64-bit

I have project created  with Visula Basic 2017 cordova. When i build the project for Android it generates android-armv7-debug.apk and android-x86-debug.apk file automatically.

I need 64bit apk file.